# How do i get object position and transform position to it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do i localize other GameObject position
and Move to it (like teleport to that object) how can i do it?

```
BotController.Player
```

it's object what i want to get position of it and move to it (teleport)
i work on game hack

Comment: Use a torch! That helps in darkness.

Comment: Uhm...I don't think it's very clear what you're asking about. Set the `transform.position` of...whatever you're moving, I guess?

Comment: If you can time travel then you can jump to the 2154 and get the Dr. Emory Erickson's transporter first version, it will limit the teleport to 40k kilometers, but for a game should be enough.

Comment: "GameHack" question, nothing helpful at all

Comment: Please review the guidelines provided on [how to ask a good question here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as your question in its present form is unlikely to attract answers which specifically address your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you already have reference to the target object you can just use `this.position = BotController.Player.position` anywhere in the object you wanna teleport.

```
public class EasyTeleporter : MonoBehavior 
{
...
    public void SomeFunction() 
    {
        position = BotController.Player.position
    }
}
```

If you are creating first person game and want to achieve something like teleporter to any object you should use raycasting for that.

For example you can take Unity default asset FirstPersonCharacter (available on asset store or you can add it when starting a new project) and add the following script to the FirstPersonCharacter gameobject (wich is child of FPSController prefab):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerTeleporter : MonoBehaviour
{

    bool shooting = false;

    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            shooting = true;
        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (shooting)
        {
            shooting = false;

            RaycastHit hit;
// you are casting a ray in front of your camera wich hits the first collider in its path
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, 100f))
            {
// normally you shouldn't teleport directly into the trget object
                transform.position = hit.transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Generally you should clarify you question. What game you are creating, what are the target and object of teleportation and how do you wanna trigger that.